# Creating local db table in Visual Studio 2013 fails

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I am trying to create a simple local database per this walkthrough:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx

When I right click on "Tables" underneath my .mdf data connection in Server Explorer and select "Add New Table" I get an error dialog saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."   This unfortunately must be a common error because there are tons of people asking about it over the last decade for various reasons.  I have tried the usual (restart VS, reboot, etc) and it always gives the same error.  What am I missing?   Running Win 7 x64 with VS 2013 Ultimate Update 4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am running Visual Studio 2013 Premium, Update 5.  I just followed the steps of the walkthrough (up to the point of creating the table) exactly as indicated and was able to create a table without issue.  I suggest that you might want to install Update 5 or possibly "repair" your Visual studio instance.

"Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" is an exception that occurs whenever a piece of code assumes that an object has been instantiated, but it hasn't.  For example:

```
Class Dog
{
    string Breed {get; set;}
    int Weight {get; set;}
}

...

    Dog MyDog;
    MyDog.Breed = "Collie"; -- Exception!

    MyDog = new Dog();
    MyDog.Breed = "Yorkie"; --  Works.
```

Since I did not set `MyDog` to an instance of the class, `Dog`, but instead left it uninstantiated and tried to reference the `Breed` property, I would get this exception.

Since you did not need to create any code in your walkthrough, then the source of the exception must be code that is internal to Visual studio.  So you will most likely need to repair Visual Studio in some way.  The easier way I can think of is to first try installing the most recent updates.  If that doesn't work, see if your installation media has a "Repair" feature.  (I don't recall if it does or not.)  Finally, you could try uninstalling it and reinstalling it entirely.  But that is a reasonably lengthy process.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  I updated to 5 and went through the repair, neither made any difference.  As you said, I don't even have any db code.  This is an error that VS itself is generating trying to add things to the project, so it must be some kind of non-obvious gremlin.  I can't waste any more time on this so I am just using sqlite .net via nuget.